# Parsing console application arguments

Tags: c#, parsing, console

In our console app, the parsing of application arguments is done like so:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace Generator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var param1 = args.SingleOrDefault(arg => arg.StartsWith("p1:"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
            {
                param1  = param1.Replace("p1:", "");
            }
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to be called like this:

> ```
> `Generator.exe p1:somevalue`
> ```

Is there a better/simpler way to parse arguments?

Comment: Also, [the FubuCore library](https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubucore) has a pretty powerful and self-documenting command line args parser, that I briefly described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6314555/390819)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd recommend taking advantage of the excellent [Mono.Options](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html) module.  It's a single `.cs` file you can drop in to your solution and get full-featured parsing of GNU getopt-style command lines.  (Things like `-x -y -z`, which is equivalent to `-xyz`, or `-k value`, or `--long-opt`, and so forth.)

Comment: from 2018: Microsoft added their own code to the file. Now you **CAN NOT** use it as a separated file. Thanks MS. [This is the latest tag without MS's intervention I've found](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-5.0.1.1/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs)

Comment: @maxkoryukov I don't get your logic. It's still licensed under the MIT license, which explicitly says it can be copied in part or in whole, as long as the license is included with it. So as of this writing in 2019 you can still take [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mono/mono/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) on its own. Unless you have something about irrationally avoiding everything Microsoft has ever touched, in which case you should know that StackExchange runs on Microsoft software.

Comment: @NicHartley, you are right, it is still **MIT-licensed**. Sorry, but I _don't remember_ what I meant then, so I can't explain my comment now... Yes, I don't like the MS-development way and their style in the software world, overall. But who am I )))

Comment: @maxkoryukov urgh, sorry for my tone there -- I genuinely didn't mean any sarcasm, but rereading my comment it _really_ sounded like it. And yeah, it's perfectly fair to dislike Microsoft. My issue is just with people avoiding everything they've ever had contact with, even indirectly by someone becoming a developer for them, because of some "taint" that they have, and (as it's been MIT-licensed the whole time) that's what I immediately jumped to. I guess I like imagining the worst of people. Sorry :(

Comment: @NicHartley don't apologize;) there was an error in my comment (and it is still there) — I can't explain that comment in any other way. And I don't know why I wrote that comment. `Mono.Options` is still a decent piece of C# code, in spite of the fact of MS interventions

Answer (score 23):

With such an implementation you will have to repeat yourself for each param.

Alternative:

```
var parsedArgs = args
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] {':'}, 1))
    .ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
string p1 = parsedArgs["p1"];
```

Comment: +1: I would have used '='. And check that arguments are prefixed with '--'. And what about where the value is the next argument not in the same argument?

Comment: @Martin why would you prefix arguments with '--'?

Comment: @frennky: Its sort of a standard for command line arguments (--<longName> or -<shortName>). It separates flags (which modify behavior) from inputs/outputs. But re-reading your original question I was over generalizing and this is not what you want.

Comment: @frennky - I agree with Martin, if you are writing an application which somebody (except you) will use then you should read about console argument standarts. As far as I know '--' is kind of *nix style, in windows it is more about slashes.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/4794). There, the consensus seems to be [Mono.Options](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html) as already suggested here by [josh3736](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/369/is-there-a-better-way-to-parse-console-application-arguments/387#387).

Comment: Read further down the list of answers on that SO question and you'll see that http://ndesk.org/Options has 2x the upvotes of the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, the answer you refer to says "I would strongly suggest using NDesk.Options (Documentation) and/or Mono.Options (same API, different namespace)."

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't use complex command line arguments, so I use a [very Simple Command Line Arguments Parser](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/03/c-simple-command-line-arguments-parser/), but it can be used as a foundation for your own application specific parameter presenter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use foreach for iterating through the agruments and then for your argument with index 1 you could use regular expression to retrieve parsed text after p1:

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using loops. As for Regex, I think it would be too much, the pattern is quite simple.

Answer (score -2):

Please check solution from link. IT uses linq. It short and reuseble in my opinion. Provides extension method so you just do somethink like:

```
args.Process(
           () => Console.WriteLine("Usage is switch1=value1,value2 switch2=value3"),
           new CommandLine.Switch("switch1",
               val => Console.WriteLine("switch 1 with value {0}",
                   string.Join(" ", val))),
           new CommandLine.Switch("switch2",
               val => Console.WriteLine("switch 2 with value {0}",
                   string.Join(" ", val)), "s1"));
   }
```

for details please visit [my blog](http://lukasz-lademann.blogspot.com/2013/01/c-command-line-arguments-parser.html)